# Exception: OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: './kubectl' when publish to Azure Function App

Tags: azure, exec, kubectl

I'm trying to write an API and publish and run on Azure Function app. And in the function I need to read from kubectl.
 Reading kubectl and configuration works fine on localhost.
 But when I publish to azure function app, it returns me error message: "Exception: OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: './kubectl'".

I'm creating  an HTTP triggered function in Azure using Python on a mac device. And the Azure service plan is LinusDynamicPlan. The kubectl I'm using is a mac binary.

Code to read kubectl :

```py
deployments = subprocess.check_output(["./kubectl", "get", "deployments", cluster_config_name])
```

I can successfully run the script on localhost. But not in Azure function app.
The error message I get in Azure:

```
2019-07-09T07:37:38.168 [Error] Executed 'Functions.nc6v3_usage' (Failed, Id=71d76d36-95ab-4bd6-9656-5578141c4c3f)
Result: Failure
Exception: OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: './kubectl'

Stack:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 300, in _handle__invocation_request
    self.__run_sync_func, invocation_id, fi.func, args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 389, in __run_sync_func
    return func(**params)

  File "/home/site/wwwroot/nc6v3_usage/__init__.py", line 18, in main
    deployments = subprocess.check_output(["./kubectl", "get", "deployments", cluster_config_name])

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 423, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The kubectl I'm using is a mac binary.

Please correct me if I didn't understand you properly. Are you using mac binary on a Linux system in your Azure instance ? If so, you just cannot do it, Mac =/= Linux.

Try to install `kubectl` on your Azure instance following [this instruction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-linux) provided by official Kubernetes docummentation and then provide the full path to kubectl binary installed for your system to your script. If you follow the above instruction it will be `/usr/local/bin/kubectl`.

Comment: Yes that's the problem. I change to Linux kubectl and it works now. Thank you so much!